# How to automatically open files when double clicking with dart editor?

Tags: dart, winscp, dart-editor

I'm using winscp to upload files and when i double click a .dart file on my server, darteditor opens but it doesn't actually open the file. how can i do this?

Comment: Did you associate .dart with Dart in Window Explorer or in WinSCP?
In general take a look at:
http://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a issue reported on Dart Editor. You can find it here - https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=344

Note: Please star the issue so that its gets some attention.